# Woocommerce automatically update price on quantity change price format

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

To automatically update the prices when the quantity button is pressed, I use a snippet. The problem is that it does not show the price in the right format, there is no thousands separator.
I would like it to show 123.456 Ft, but now it shows 123456 Ft.

The relevant part of the code is:

$price = $product->get_price();

[...]

```
 wc_enqueue_js( "      
        $( '[name=quantity]' ).on( 'input change', function() {
            var qty = $( this ).val();
            var price = '" . esc_js( $price ) . "';
            var price_string = ( price*qty ).toFixed(0);
            // Greater than
            if ( qty > 1 ) {
        $('#subtot > span').html(price_string+'' " . esc_js( $currency ) . "');
            } else {
                $( '#subtot > span').html( '' );
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ECMAScript Internationalization API, and in particular the [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) object.

In this object, you can pass in a Locale and an Options object with options for currency, in order for the format to output the appropriate currency symbol.
You can check the example section in the above link for more info.

In your case, you can use something like this (I only included the JS code in order to keep code highlighting, since it is inside a string):

```js
    $( '[name=quantity]' ).on( 'input change', function() {
        const qty = $( this ).val();
        const price = '" . esc_js( $price ) . "';
        // var price_string = ( price*qty ).toFixed(0);
        // Greater than
        if ( qty > 1 ) {
            const priceFormatted = new Intl.NumberFormat(
                'hu-HU', // locales
                { // options
                    style: 'currency', 
                    currency: 'HUF'
                }
            ).format(price * qty);
            $('#subtot > span').html(priceFormatted);
        } else {
            $( '#subtot > span').html( '' );
        }
    ... REST OF YOUR CODE
```

The following lists of Locales and Currencies may come in handy:

- [Locales (BCP 47 language tags)](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/language_tags.php)
- [Currencies (ISO 4217 currency code list)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#List_of_ISO_4217_currency_codes)

EDIT based on comment:

In order to have comma as thousands separator you can use something like this:

```js
const priceFormatted = new Intl.NumberFormat(
    "hu-HU", 
    { 
        style: 'currency', 
        currency: 'HUF',
        maximumFractionDigits: 2, // Set to zero if you want to not display the decimal part at all.
        trailingZeroDisplay: "stripIfInteger" // Remove the decimal part if they are all zero.
    }
).format(price) // This will output '1 702 180 Ft'
.replace(/\s/g, ',') // Replace any whitespace with comma. This will output: '1,702,180,Ft'
.replace(',Ft', ' Ft'); // Fix last comma before currency symbol. This will output: '1,702,180 Ft'


// Alternative by using another locale that formats the number with commas as thousands separators.
const priceFormatted = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
}).format(price)
+ ' Ft'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's better than before, but it's still not perfect.
There are not enough thousand separators and the decimal point should not be at the end.

Currently this is the output with your code: 1 702 180,00 Ft
I want this format: 1,702,180 Ft

Any idea? :(

Comment: This has to do with the locale. The hu_HU uses spaces for thousands separator. Thus, you can use this locale and then chain the replaceAll fn in order to convert the spaces to commas and one more replace to fix the last comma before the currency symbol. 
As an alternative, you can use another locale, that uses commas as thousand separator and then attach the currency symbol in the end. 
As for the decimal point, there are some options that you can pass to the Intl.NumberFormat constructor in order to not display it at all or only when it is only zeros (e.g. .000).
See my edit for examples.